# Выбор технологии для сложного GUI на C#

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Как лучше сделать GUI похожий как на картинке?
Экран может менять размеры, значения будут изменяться постоянно.
запускать под windows 7-11.
Думаю сделать на WPF. Unity не знаю.
Спасибо за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего необычного, своих контролов можете сколько угодно сделать вплоть до полной объектной модели этой картинки. Делайте на WPF, юзерконтролы в помощь, для попиксельного позиционирования можно использовать `Canvas`. Статические элементы можно на фон положить картинкой для облегчения, остальное - контролы. Почитайте про привязки данных и MVVM в WPF перед тем как начать. Ну а дальше XAML, стили, тригеры и поехали.

Comment: Окно переменного размера, разве Canvas подойдёт?

Comment: Как одна конкретная схема может быть переменного размера? Если вы про масштабирование, то варианта 2 - ScrollViewer и Viewbox. Вы же не считаете, что если например канвас 10000x10000, то его невозможно отобразить?